# How to limit a call to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently looking for the best solution to limit the number of requests to a function.

Example:

```
function CheckData() {
    if (d == "newdata") {
        GetData(2);
    }
}

function GetData(getcheck) {
    // Ajax Request here
}
```

The solution I am looking for is a way so that when CheckData calls GetData is there a way to limit how often it can call GetData, or better still if there is a bulk of requests that has suddenly come through, is there a way to make it say only get the last request?
So basically can it check the frequency of requests so that you can say its stopped a bulk of requests send the last one now?

I am just looking for a way to limit how often CheckData can call GetData but the best possible way to minimize wait.

I have looked at a few solutions and I am not sure how to apply it to this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
Usuals pattern to limit the number of time a function can be called are:

[throttle](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L3416) and [debounce](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L3209)

(You can also see similar implementation in underscore.js)

**Option 2**
Although for ajax, you could create a **queue system** to limit one request at a time on the same ressources.

**Option 3**
Or, if your function always get the same ressources, just check if the request is over or not:

```
var GetData = (function() {
    var running = false;
    return function(getcheck) {
        // exit if ajax is running
        if ( running ) { return; }

        running = true;

        $.ajax(/* go */)
            .done(function() {
                /* do stuff with data */

                // call it over
                running = false;
            });
    }
}());

function CheckData() {
    if (d == "newdata") {
        GetData(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I am not sure what is the best option :S.. Its basically to limit requests to get new shouts. I want it to check for them every sec but not burst requests if there is a bunch of them in 1 go.

This line is giving me error in javascript?
// exit if ajax is running
        running && return;
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell you the best option without more detail on your application use case. **Option one** will limit number of call to a function per seconds, or will limit to one function call per "call bunch". Read doc here for more about those: http://underscorejs.org/#throttle. **Option 2** would basically cache server response which don't seems like what you need. And **Option 3** will only allow one server call simultaneously.